# Azure AD authorization directly from mobile app

Tags: azure, xamarin, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms application where user should Authorize using `Azure AD B2C`. I've managed it just fine using [this library](https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticating-mobile-apps-with-azure-active-directory-b2c/).

Now I'd like to know if it is possible to authorize without redirecting to `webview`. When user enters email and password on app send a get request directly to an url and receive `access token`, `refresh token` and etc. Just like in `OAuth 2.0`.

I've researched and found out that skipping the webview authentication part is doable but extremely not recommended for security reasons but anyway, would be glad to hear any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Webview runs on SSL (https) and hence transmission of user credentials for authentication is secured.

*It’s worth noting that you don’t have to use a web view for authentication; you may create your own user interface for this flow and pass the information back to MSAL.*
- this is mentioned on the same blog-post which you referred to.

All you have to do is to design your own interface and pass back the login info. It seems like a little work to do.